# tableview does not update

Tags: ios, swift4.2, xcode9.4

i'm trying to make a ordering food app for restaurants, when i add items to the cart for the first time table view loads the singleton array i've made. but when i go back to the menu and choose another item the array is updated but the table view of the cart doesn't, i'm using tabbarcontroller. tried to use tableview.reloadData() in different places still new data added to the array doesn't appear

```
class CartVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var priceLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.reloadData()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()

        updateView()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return DataService.instance.cartItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell") as? CartCell{
            let item = DataService.instance.cartItems[indexPath.row]
            cell.configCell(cart: item)
            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            DataService.instance.cartItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            updateView()
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }

    func updateView(){
        var sum = 0
        for item in DataService.instance.cartItems{
            sum += item.itemPrice * item.quantity
            print(item.itemPrice)
        }
        priceLbl.text = "$\(sum)"
    }

    @IBAction func orderPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // upload order to firebase, clear cart and move to orderVC
    }


}
```

Comment: @yourssef i in tabbar `viewDidLoad` called only once. Will you please check reload in `viewWillAppear`. Also check your array does your new value added in the array and then reload will called?

Comment: After the modification of the property `DataService.instance.cartItems`, you need to reload your table view. You need to somehow notify (possibly delegation, callback closure) your `CartVC` where you will perform `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: @chiragshah were should i add viewwillappear?? in the cartVC or the mainTabBarVC. and yes new values are added to the array

Comment: @youssefSULTAN add in CartVC

Comment: @chiragshah it worked thank you

Comment: @youssefSULTAN let me post answer. Please upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tabbar every time `viewDidLoad` not called so you need to reload the data in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. Here is the reference.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        updateView()
    }
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewDelegate is not reactive. You have to call reloadData() when you want to update the tableView content (when your DataService.instance value is updated).

In a MVP world, your "add" action will trigger an event to the presenter. And the presenter sends back to the view an action to update the tableView, after updating your DataService.

Maybe you should look at [RxSwift/ReactiveCocoa](https://medium.com/@navdeepsingh_2336/creating-an-ios-app-with-mvvm-and-rxswift-in-minutes-b8800633d2e8), which provides APIs to automatically bind your `DataService.instance` array to the cells rendered in the UITableView.